# understanding dll dependencies

Tags: c++, dll

I'm building a c++ DLL in visual studio 2008.

For some reason, even when I build in release mode, my dll still depends on msvcr90d.dll.
I can see that using depends.exe

Is there any way to figure out what is causing this dependency?
My run-time library setting is /MD

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Dependency Walker (depends.exe) shows all functions which are called by your application, so you can figure out which functions it calls from msvcr90d.dll, meybe it helps

Comment: Perhaps you include some static lib which depends on a debug runtime?

Comment: I've added the "Display All Progress Messages (/VERBOSE)" flag to the linker setting. It now shows which library is loaded for each symbol.

Comment: @DanJ - so what was the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Project properties go to the `"Configuration Properties"/Linker/General` panel.  Change the `"Show Progress"` property to `"Display All Progress Messages (/VERBOSE)"`.

The linker will now tell you exactly why  it's pulling in `msvcr90d.dll`

If you're building from the command line, use the `/VERBOSE` linker option (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

May be a very dumb answer..but isn't exploring the tree structure displayed in the depends.exe show which dll is causing msvcr90d.dll linkage?